# Which div has a fixed width?

Tags: html, css

I have some arbitrarily nested `div` elements using `display: inline-block` like this:

```
<div class="div-0">
    <div class="div-1">
        <div class="div-01"></div>
        <div class="div-02"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="div-2">
        <div class="div-01"></div>
        <div class="div-02"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="div-3">
        <div class="div-01"></div>
        <div class="div-02"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="div-4">
        <div class="div-01"></div>
        <div class="div-02"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="div-5">
        <div class="div-01"></div>
        <div class="div-02"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Somebody has hidden a specific CSS rule somewhere that's something like this:

```css
.div-0 .div-4 .div-01 {
    min-width: 400px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

This prevents all my `div` elements from being sized smaller than 400px. How do I hunt down which rule is forcing the minimum width?

I've tried manually inspecting each `div` with Chrome's inspector, but my actual code is nested 20+ `div` elements deep and it's difficult to determine by inspection.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

div {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 25px;
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 100%;
}

.div-0 .div-4 .div-01 {
  min-width: 400px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="div-0">
    <div class="div-1">
      <div class="div-01"></div>
      <div class="div-02"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="div-2">
      <div class="div-01"></div>
      <div class="div-02"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="div-3">
      <div class="div-01"></div>
      <div class="div-02"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="div-4">
      <div class="div-01"></div>
      <div class="div-02"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="div-5">
      <div class="div-01"></div>
      <div class="div-02"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can't you search the CSS? Chrome inspector -> Sources tab -> find the CSS file (or go through all of them) and you can Ctrl-F to find rules with min-width.

Comment: Check computed styles of the div that is getting 400px and try to move up in DOM heirarchy to check where that style was applied https://ibb.co/cfvAAJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I was asking the wrong question! My suspicion was wrong – there was no developer hiding CSS rules. Instead, it was some unbreakable text inside of the `div` elements.

There was a line of text in the `div` like `Loremipsum....loremipsum` that was unable to break properly. The `div` element cound not resize smaller than the width of this long "word".

Changing the word breaking strategy fixed my problem:

```css
div {
    word-break: break-word;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Go to the 'Computed' tab of the CSS styles. There, look for the 'min-width' property. Hover over the '400px' value and you will see an arrow. Click that arrow and it will jump you to the CSS rule that is enforcing it.

Comment: That works if I already know which element has the specific rule applied (`.div-0 .div-4 .div-01` in my example). Inspecting any other div will show the `width: 100%` rule instead and won't show the true source of the fixed width.